# Selenium SendKeys in CKeditor5 does not work for me

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, sendkeys, ckeditor5

I located the ckeditor5 with `findElement(By.cssSelector("p"))`.

I was able to click inside the editor but the function `editor.sendKeys("Test")` leads to the error message:

> Cannot focus element.

Does someone have an Idea how I could put some Text inside the ck5 using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out, this worked for me: `getDriver().switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(keys);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the actions to click and sendkeys

Sample example below

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Click();
actions.SendKeys("New");
actions.Perform();
```